# How to save output from command (eg. diff) into a variable

Tags: bash

I want to test if there is any output from the `diff` (test if files are same), if none `echo "Passed $x" else echo "Failed $x"`. I came up with some intermidiate step (save the output from diff to a file then read from file)

```
diff "./helloworld$x.out" "./output/helloworld$x.out" > tmp.txt;
output="`cat tmp.txt`";

if [ "$output" = "" ];
  then
    echo "Passed $x";
  else
    echo "Failed $x";
  fi;
```

I'm sure the code can be improved? Main question is: is it possible to save the output from `diff` directly into a variable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This works:

```
if diff "./helloworld$x.out" "./output/helloworld$x.out" >/dev/null; then
    echo "Passed $x";
else
    echo "Failed $x";
fi
```

If you use a variable instead of `echo` you could drop the `else` branche: set the variable to false before the `if` and save 2 lines of code.

If you want to actually put the result into a variable use:

```
some_var="$(diff "./helloworld$x.out" "./output/helloworld$x.out")"
```

Including my test to see if it does actually work:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~$ touch 1
rinzwind@discworld:~$ touch 2
rinzwind@discworld:~$ more test
if diff 1 2 >/dev/null; then
    echo "Passed $x";
else
    echo "Failed $x";
fi
rinzwind@discworld:~$ ./test
Passed 

rinzwind@discworld:~$ vi 2
rinzwind@discworld:~$ more 2
2
rinzwind@discworld:~$ ./test
Failed
```

On the `>/dev/null` part: `>/dev/null 2>&1` will send output to `>/dev/null` and `2>&1`  will send standard errors to the same file (`&1` means 'use first parameter') in front of this command (so it also uses `/dev/null`).

sidenote: `sdiff` will show a side-by-side `diff` listings:

```
sdiff 1 2 
1                               1
2                               2
3                               3
4                               4
5                                  5
7                               7
                                  > 8
9                               9
10                              10
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I dont understand what `... > /dev/null` does in this context. The output of diff will goto /dev/null but isnt that nothing?

Comment: The diff will output all the differences between the files on your screen and >/dev/null makes sure the output of the command is redirected to oblivion. The if is still executed based on the output.

Comment: The if statement checks the exit code of the diff command. 0 means no differences were found, while 1 means there were one or more differences.

Answer (score 19):

`diff` can even suppress output completely except for the "Files /bin/bash and /bin/sh differ" message using the code below.

```
file1="./helloworld$x.out"
file2="./output/helloworld$x.out"

if diff -q "$file1" "$file2"; then
    echo "Passed $x"
else
    echo "Failed $x"
fi
```

If you even want to hide that message, you've to append `> /dev/null` after the diff command to hide the output of `diff`:

```
if diff -q "$file1" "$file2" >/dev/null; then
```

`/dev/null` is a special file that acts as a blackhole, if you write to it, it'll be gone, if you're reading from it, you'll get nothing back.

Note that bash does not need `;` to end lines.

As for the original question, to save the output of an program in a variable:

```
file1="./helloworld$x.out"
file2="./output/helloworld$x.out"
output="$(diff -q "$file1" "$file2")"

# the quotes are mandatory, this checks whether $output is empty or not
if [ -n "$output" ]; then
    echo "Passed $x"
else
    echo "Failed $x"
fi
```

Alternative ways to check whether a variable is empty:

```
[ "$output" = "" ]
[ "$output" == "" ]
[[ "$output" == "" ]]
[[ $output == "" ]]
```

If you're using Bash, the last two commands are recommended for string comparison. Otherwise, the first and `[ -n "$output" ]` is recommended.

Answer (score 6):

a) The output of command1 can be catched with

```
output=$(diff "helloworld$x.out" "output/helloworld$x.out")
```

or with backticks, but those are discouraged, because you can't nest them, and they might be hard to distinguish from apostrophs, depending on the font:

```
 output=`cmd1`
```

b) Instead of writing to a file, and then reading that file, (or grabbing the output, and then echoing it) you would use a pipe directly:

```
 cmd1 > file
 cat file | cmd2 

 output=$(cmd1)
 echo "${output}" | cmd2
```

=>

```
 cmd1 | cmd2
```

but in your example, you're not interested in the output, but the outcome of the program - did it work?

```
 diff "helloworld$x.out" "output/helloworld$x.out" && echo "success" || echo "failure"
```

To read about the use of && and || search for "shortcut AND and shortcut OR".

To keep the output clean, you can redirect the output of 'diff' to nowhere:

```
 diff "helloworld$x.out" "output/helloworld$x.out" >/dev/null && echo "success" || echo "failure"
```

To grab success and evaluate it later, you store the result of the last command in a variable with $?:

```
diff "helloworld$x.out" "output/helloworld$x.out" >/dev/null
result=$?
# do something else
case $result in 
   0) echo success ;;
   *) echo failure ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know if two files are the same or differ (but don't care what the difference actually is), `cmp` is more suitable.

```
if cmp -s file1 file2; then echo "Equal"; else echo "Not equal"; fi
```